# Criar mosaico de imagens em PHP

Tags: php

O que pretendo fazer é transformar uma imagem em um `mosaico`, onde cada `pixel` ou grupo de `pixels` da imagem seria substituído por uma foto de uma flor de cor semelhante. Ou seja, transformar uma imagem qualquer em um `mosaico` de flores. 
Já tenho toda a lógica planejada, mas a única dúvida que tenho é em como faço pra inserir a foto da flor na `imagem`.

O que meu `código` faz atualmente é substituir cada `pixel` por outro em um tom de cinza. O que quero agora é substituir esse `pixel` por uma `imagem`.

```
<?
$img = imagecreatefrompng('imagens/monalisa.png');
$largura = imagesx($img);
$altura = imagesy($img);

$c = 0;
$imagem = array();

$gd = imagecreatetruecolor($largura, $altura);

for ($j = 0; $j < $altura; $j++) {
for ($i = 0; $i < $largura; $i++) {
    $rgb = imagecolorat($img, $i, $j);
    $rgb = imagecolorsforindex($img, $rgb);

    $escala = $rgb['red'] + $rgb['green'] + $rgb['blue'];
    $nc = round($escala/3); 

    $cor = imagecolorallocate($gd, $nc, $nc, $nc);

    imagesetpixel($gd, $i,$j, $cor);
}
}

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($gd);
?>
```

Comment: Qual classe ou biblioteca você está usando para os métodos `imagecreatefrompng`, `imagecreatetruecolor`, `imagecolorallocate`, etc ?

Comment: @RaoniBZ, muito provavelmente ele está usando a biblioteca nativa do PHP, o [GD](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.image.php).

Comment: @Inkeliz obrigado !

Answer (score 0):

Consegui até o momento alocar cada foto de flor na página dando *echo* da *tag* *img*, mas o que quero exatamente é transformar numa imagem só pra salvar.

```
<?
$ft = array("imagens/margarida.png","imagens/girassol.png","imagens/rosa.png");

$img = imagecreatefrompng('imagens/monalisa.png');
$largura = imagesx($img);
$altura = imagesy($img);

$c = 0;
$imagem = array();

$gd = imagecreatetruecolor($largura, $altura);

for ($j = 0; $j < $altura; $j++) {
for ($i = 0; $i < $largura; $i++) {
    $rgb = imagecolorat($img, $i, $j);
    $rgb = imagecolorsforindex($img, $rgb);

    $escala = $rgb['red'] + $rgb['green'] + $rgb['blue'];
    $nc = round((2 * $escala)/765); 

    //echo $nc . ' ';
    echo '<img src="'. $ft[$nc] .'"/>';

    //$cor = imagecolorallocate($gd, $nc, $nc, $nc);

    //imagesetpixel($gd, $i,$j, $cor);
}
echo '<br>';
}

//header('Content-Type: image/png');
//imagepng($gd);
?>
```

Por enquanto, está assim:

[Imagem normal](http://lucaswmolin.com/portfolio/colorido/normal.php)

[Mosaico](http://lucaswmolin.com/portfolio/mosaico/mosaico.php)

Comment: Qual classe ou biblioteca você está usando para os métodos `imagecreatefrompng, imagecreatetruecolor, imagecolorallocate`, etc ?